# Does Black rock island keep changing with the sky?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

In the film *Pirates of Caribbean: Dead Man Tell No Tales*,  we learn that "Black rock island" is perfect a reflection of the heavens.

> "Look at it, Jack. It's the most beautiful thing I've ever seen. This
>   is what my father wanted me to find."
>   "Rocks!"
>   "No, not rocks.
>   Stars. This is the Map No Man Can Read. This island is a perfect
>   reflection of the heavens."

―Carina Smyth and Jack Sparrow

But we know that the sky changes over the year. So does the island also change with it?

Comment: I think it's good Q. On one hand the merfolk are the one's who put the trident in Poseidon's tomb when Jack was a boy, so there is more than one way to get to it, but you're right, that doesn't mean that the Island couldn't move and only comes back to Poseidon's Tomb location when there's a blood moon, but I'm not sure why it would be necessary since being able to read the map and the jewels on the Island only work then?

Answer (score 2):

When Carina said,

> This is the Map No Man Can Read. This island is a perfect reflection of the heavens.

What she meant is that island resembled the galaxy full of stars.
Because it was full of gems and reflected light in magnificent manner.

So NO, the island didn't change over the years.

Comment: The word "perfect reflection" means otherwise, moreover the constellation of sky which was in Barbossa's diary also present in island. I think,maybe reflection matches only in that time of year